# Bash - is this called a definition?

Tags: bash, definition, heredoc, command-substitution

I'm pretty new to bash,

I learned about using variables like this:

```
var=$(cat << EOF
this is echoed
and this as well...
EOF
)

echo "$var"
```

if the above code is called using a `variable` how do you call the approach below? is this called a using a `definition`?

```
def="This should be echoed\nand this as well...\n"

printf "$def"
```

I'm asking about the right terminology of the second approach.

Comment: I do not understand what your problem is?

Comment: In the evaluation for var you have what is commonly referred to as a heredoc, is that the question?

Comment: @Jdamian, sorry for not making it clear, I updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `var` and `def` are variables; that is, they are the names of string-data in your current environment, accessed using `$` as in your examples.

To create each variable, you *assign* a string to it. This is called an *assignment*. Syntactically, `=` is the *assignment operator*.

Once `var` and `def` are assigned, there is no difference in how they store data; the stored data in each case is merely a string.

There is nothing "special" requiring additional terminology in the assignment of `def`. However, there are two interesting aspects of the `var` assignment:

- As alluded to in a comment, your use of `cat` is a pattern called a ["here document"](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html).
- To create and capture the "document" (which is just a string), you are using `$()`, which is a form of ["command substitution"](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html).